# Obtain the solution of the equation$y(x)=F(x)+\lambda \int_a^b K(x,\xi)y(\xi)d\xi $ Where,$K(x,\xi)=u(x)v(\xi)$.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-equations, eigenfunctions

> Obtain the solution of the equation$$y(x)=F(x)+\lambda \int_a^b
>  K(x,\xi)y(\xi)d\xi $$ Where,$$K(x,\xi)=u(x)v(\xi)$$
>
> in the form $$y(x)=F(x)+\lambda \frac{\int_a^b K(x,\xi)F(\xi)d\xi
> }{1-\lambda\int_a^b K(x,x)dx }$$

Solution:We're given that $$y(x)=F(x)+\lambda \int_a^b
 K(x,\xi)y(\xi)d\xi \tag{$*$}$$ Where,$$K(x,\xi)=u(x)v(\xi)$$ Putting the value of $K(x,\xi)$ in the equation (*),we get $$y(x)=F(x)+\lambda \int_a^b
 u(x)v(\xi)y(\xi)d\xi=F(x)+\lambda u(x)\int_a^b v(\xi)y(\xi)d\xi$$.

Let,**$c=\int_a^b v(\xi)y(\xi)d\xi$**.

Then,$y(x)=F(x)+\lambda u(x)c$

Now, i need to determine the value of "$c$".But, i'm not getting, how to determine it?

Please give some hint/suggestions about the method by which i can proceed further...

Thank you...

Comment: It is a Fredholm equation of the second kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation).

Comment: @JeanMarie:I do not get anything for determining "$c$" from your suggested link.Will you please shed some more light on the problem.....like some properties of definite integrals(if there is any..).

Comment: I answer to your question by another question : Were you aware that your issue has a well established (Fredholm) theory behind it ? I ask this to avoid you re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: @JeanMarie:I'm a beginner in Integral equations.I've read Fredholm theory,but i'm not very used to of it.Actually,i find this problem in my text book and i find it interesting,so i attempted it but got struck in between.Now,please tell me what sould i study in  order to deal with this problem.If you want,you may answer this via similar question.

Comment: Your problem is that "c" (I have understood now what you meant by "c" !) is not at all a constant because it contains the **unknown** function $y$.

Comment: @JeanMarie:thanks for your first comment.IT was useful,there  a found about a redefined version of a notion in Linear algebra called "Fredholm Alternative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying the equation $y(x)=F(x)+\lambda\,c\,u(x)$ by $v(x)$ and integration $[a,b]$ we get
$$
c=\int_a^bF(x)\,v(x)\,dx+\lambda\,c\int_a^bu(x)\,v(x)\,dx.
$$
This gives you the value of $c$.

Comment: @@Julián Aguirre:Thanks...